# trying to vertify my PIN in a I/O file to a GUI

Tags: java

im working on my assignment and i can't seem to work out :

1. Opening the input file
2. Reading the PIN from the input file and storing the value in a variable
3. Verifying that a PIN it is given matches that value
4. Asking the user to enter a PIN
5. Asking the account whether or not the current PIN is valid

i think first 2 is for myAccount and 3rd one for somewhere in myAccount.checkPin(input). while 4 and 5 is something to do with my GUI.

i can't figure out what codes should i put in it.

BankAccount (I/O file)

```
//import statements
import java.util.*;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;


public class BankAccount
{
//BankAccount data

private double balance = 0.0;
private String pin = "";


//===========Constructor=========
public BankAccount()
{
    //When BankAccount is instantiated we must read in
    //the PIN and the previous balance from a text file
    balance = 1000;


}

//=========PUBLIC METHODS===========
public void deposit(double amount)
{
    balance = balance + amount;
}
public void withdraw(double amount)
{
    balance = balance - amount;
}
public double getBalance()
{
    return balance;
}
public boolean checkPin(String userPin)
{
    //TO DO
    return true;
}

//========PRIVATE METHODS===========
//Private because they should not be called outside this class


private void readFile()
{
    try
    {
        //add code to open file
        FileReader fin = new FileReader("BankAccount.txt");

        //Read in the stored PIN and bank Balance
        Scanner in = new Scanner(fin);

        //Close file
        in.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
    }
}
private void writeFile()
{
    try
    {
        //add code to open file
        PrintWriter fout = new PrintWriter("BankAccount.txt");


        //write the PIN and current balance to file
        fout.println("Pin: " + pin);
        fout.println("Balance: " + balance);


        //close file
        fout.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

ATM_GUI (GUI)

```
//import statements
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ATM_GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
//class data:GUI components and the BankAccount object

//Declare any fields and GUI components here
private JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();

private JLabel myLabel = new JLabel("Amount: $");

private JButton myButton1 = new JButton("Deposit");
private JButton myButton2 = new JButton("Withdraw");
private JButton myButton3 = new JButton("Balance");
private JButton myButton4 = new JButton("Change PIN");

private JTextField numberField = new JTextField(10);

//Instantiate BankAccount
BankAccount myAccount = new BankAccount();

public ATM_GUI()
{
    //Build the GUI
    add(myPanel);

    myPanel.add(myLabel);

    myPanel.add(numberField);

    myPanel.add(myButton1);
    myPanel.add(myButton2);
    myPanel.add(myButton3);
    myPanel.add(myButton4);

    //make the buttons active authenticateUSer();
    myButton4.addActionListener(this);
    myButton3.addActionListener(this);
    myButton2.addActionListener(this);
    myButton1.addActionListener(this);
}
//code to perform user-authetication.depends on your updates to
//bank account. you may like to comment out this method initially
//so that you can compile other parts of your code.

private void authenticateUser()
{
    String input = "";
    //NOte that you'll need to create the checkPin(...) method
    //in the BankAccount class before this will compile.

    while (!myAccount.checkPin(input))
    {
        //pop up an input box so the user can enter their PIN

    }
}

//if your buttons have actonlisteners, this method will be
//invoked whenever a button is clicked

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    //figure out which button was pressed
    String buttonClicked = e.getActionCommand();

    //Write code to perform the task for each button
    if(buttonClicked.equals("Withdraw"))
    {
        double amount = getNumberFromGUI();

        //perform withdrawal task...
        myAccount.withdraw(amount);

    }
    //use else if to contunue processing for the other buttons
    else if (buttonClicked.equals("Change PIN"))
    {
        String response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your PIN");
    }
    else if (buttonClicked.equals("Deposit"))
    {
        double amount = getNumberFromGUI();
        myAccount.deposit(amount);
    }
    else if (buttonClicked.equals("Balance"))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Balance = "+ myAccount.getBalance());

    }
}
//here is some nice code to handle the situation when unexpected
//data is entered by the user. it prevents exceptions from
//being thrown. you may use it if you like. but not essential.
private double getNumberFromGUI()
{
    double retVal = 0;
    String input = numberField.getText();
    try
    {
        retVal = Double.parseDouble(input);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Bad data entered.");
    }
    return retVal;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //instantiate ATM_GUI
    JFrame theGUI = new ATM_GUI();

    //set title
    theGUI.setTitle("ATM_GUI");

    //set default closeoperation
    theGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //set frame size
    theGUI.setSize(250,150);

    //set visibility
    theGUI.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Is your question "What codes should I put in?"? Because that's way too broad.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis well kinda yeah like what codes should i add to vertify a PIN and add one too

Answer (score 2):

You've got your steps wrong:

1. Open input file (`BankAccount.readFile()`)
2. Read PIN from file and store it into a variable (`BankAccount.readFile()`)
3. Ask user to enter a PIN (`ATM_GUI.authenticateUser()`)
4. Verify that the PIN is correct (`BankAccount.checkPin()`)

   ```
   //import statements
   import java.util.*;
   import java.io.FileReader;
   import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
   import java.io.PrintWriter;

   public class BankAccount {
   // BankAccount data

   private double balance = 0.0;
   private String pin = null;

   // ===========Constructor=========
   public BankAccount() {
       // When BankAccount is instantiated we must read in
       // the PIN and the previous balance from a text file
       balance = 1000;
       readFile();
   }

   // =========PUBLIC METHODS===========
   public void deposit(double amount) {
       balance = balance + amount;
   }

   public void withdraw(double amount) {
       balance = balance - amount;
   }

   public double getBalance() {
       return balance;
   }

   public boolean checkPin(String userPin) {
       // check if pin has been loaded
       if (pin != null) {
           if (pin.equals(userPin)) {
               return true;
           }
           return false;
       }
       // you may want to replace this with an exception
       return false;
   }

   // ========PRIVATE METHODS===========
   // Private because they should not be called outside this class

   private void readFile() {
       try {
           // add code to open file
           FileReader fin = new FileReader("BankAccount.txt");

           // Read in the stored PIN and bank Balance
           Scanner in = new Scanner(fin);

           pin = in.nextLine();

           // Close file
           in.close();
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       }
   }

   private void writeFile() {
       try {
           // add code to open file
           PrintWriter fout = new PrintWriter("BankAccount.txt");

           // write the PIN and current balance to file
           fout.println("Pin: " + pin);
           fout.println("Balance: " + balance);

           // close file
           fout.close();
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

       }
   }
   }
   ```

I'll leave the GUI part for you to do...

All you need to do is read input (the PIN) from the user, and call `myAccount.checkPin()` on the user input